# Laravel mail attachments

Tags: php, laravel

I want to attach more than one file to the mail sent.

Mail facade:

```
  public function build()
{
    return $this->from('noreply@webpts.co.za')
                ->to('johan.dutoit@nhls.ac.za')
                ->view('mails.demo')
                ->text('mails.demo_plain')
                ->with(
                  [
                        'testVarOne' => '1',
                        'testVarTwo' => '2',
                  ])
                  ->attach(public_path('/img').'/NHLS.jpg', [
                          'as' => 'NHLS.jpg',
                          'mime' => 'image/jpeg',
                        ]);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem here?Attachment not sending?

Comment: Attaching more files.

Answer (score 2):

You can store all of your attachment in array and then loop through it to attach all the attachments

```
  $attachments = [
        // first attachment
        '/path/to/file1',

        // second attachment
        '/path/to/file2',
        ...
    ];

public function build()
{
    $email = $this->view('mails.demo')->subject('Test subject')
                ->from('noreply@webpts.co.za')
                ->to('johan.dutoit@nhls.ac.za')
                ->text('mails.demo_plain');

    // $attachments is an array with file paths of attachments
    foreach($attachments as $filePath){
        $email->attach($filePath);
    }
    return $email;
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I get the error ""syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)""

Answer (score 1):

To attach multiple files, just chain multiple `attach` calls like so `->attach(...file1 params)->attach(...file2 params)` and so on

Comment: I used this not the files I want to attach is pfd. Now I get the error "Unable to open file for reading"   [code]  ->attach(public_path('/img').'/NHLS.jpg',[
                              'as' => 'demo.jpg',
                              'mime' => 'image/jpeg'])
                      ->attach(public_path('/storage/agreements'), [
                                'as' => 'agreement_41.pdf',
                                'mime' => 'application/pdf']);